Query with joins to build product with options
I have created the below select query that joins 5 SQL tables. The modifier table either uses the NAME column to display the modifier name or the ITEM_RECORD_KEY column to reference the RECORD_KEY of the ITEM row from the ITEM table to display the Modifier name.
My query only returns the modifier name if it does not references the ITEM_RECORD_KEY. I need to return either the MODIFIER.NAME or the ITEM.NAME in the MODIFIER column of my query result.
Query:
SELECT
    I.NAME AS 'ITEM NAME',
    ML.NAME AS 'MODIFIER LIST',
    MG.NAME AS 'MODIFIER GROUP',
    M.NAME AS 'MODIFIER',
    FORMAT(CAST(M.UPCHARGE_EXPRESSION AS numeric), 'c', 'en-us') AS 'UPCHARGE'
FROM 
    ITEM
RIGHT JOIN 
    [dbo].[ITEM] I ON I.RECORD_KEY = I.RECORD_KEY
RIGHT JOIN 
    [dbo].[ITEM_MODIFIER] IM ON IM.ITEM_RECORD_KEY = I.RECORD_KEY
RIGHT JOIN 
    [dbo].[MODIFIER_LIST] ML ON ML.RECORD_KEY = IM.MODIFIER_LIST_RECORD_KEY
RIGHT JOIN 
    [dbo].[MODIFIER_GROUP] MG ON MG.MODIFIER_LIST_RECORD_KEY = ML.RECORD_KEY
RIGHT JOIN 
    [dbo].[MODIFIER] M ON M.MODIFIER_GROUP_RECORD_KEY = MG.RECORD_KEY
GROUP BY 
    I.NAME, ML.NAME, MG.NAME, M.NAME, M.UPCHARGE_EXPRESSION
ORDER BY 
    I.NAME, ML.NAME, MG.NAME, M.NAME

This is the current results from that query:



ITEM NAME
MODIFIER LIST
MODIFIER GROUP
MODIFIER
UPCHARGE




$2 sundae sale
ICE CREAM FLAVORS
CHOOSE ICE CREAM
NULL
NULL


$2 sundae sale
ICE CREAM FLAVORS
CHOOSE ICE CREAM
CHOOSE LATER
NULL



[Here is proof that the above query runs]
(https://i.sstatic.net/7o1QDkbe.png)
This is the expected results I am trying to get from my query:



ITEM NAME
MODIFIER LIST
MODIFIER GROUP
MODIFIER
UPCHARGE




$2 sundae sale
ICE CREAM FLAVORS
CHOOSE ICE CREAM
BLACK RASP IC
NULL


$2 sundae sale
ICE CREAM FLAVORS
CHOOSE ICE CREAM
CHOC CHIP IC
NULL


$2 sundae sale
ICE CREAM FLAVORS
CHOOSE ICE CREAM
CHOC CHOC CHIP IC
NULL


$2 sundae sale
ICE CREAM FLAVORS
CHOOSE ICE CREAM
CHOOSE LATER
NULL


$2 sundae sale
ICE CREAM FLAVORS
CHOOSE ICE CREAM
COFFEE IC
NULL


$2 sundae sale
ICE CREAM FLAVORS
CHOOSE ICE CREAM
COOKIE DOUGH IC
NULL


$2 sundae sale
ICE CREAM FLAVORS
CHOOSE ICE CREAM
STRAWBERRY IC
NULL


$2 sundae sale
ICE CREAM FLAVORS
CHOOSE ICE CREAM
VANILLA IC
NULL


$2 sundae sale
ICE CREAM FLAVORS
CHOOSE ICE CREAM
VEGAN OREO
NULL



Here are the tables to reproduce the database:
[ITEM] table (data types bigint and nvarchar(128)):



RECORD_KEY
NAME




5935753887661641498
COOKIE DOUGH IC


5935753858146389769
BLACK RASP IC


5935753875199381267
CHOC CHIP IC


5935753885692612377
COFFEE IC


5935753956554460991
STRAWBERRY IC


5935753967705804613
VANILLA IC


5935753973608501064
VEGAN OREO


5935753877166837524
CHOC CHOC CHIP IC


3189656780758021441
$2 sundae sale



[MODIFIER_LIST] table (datatypes bigint and nvarchar(128))



RECORD_KEY
NAME




5992426424268357750
ICE CREAM FLAVORS



[MODIFIER_GROUP] table (datatypes bigint, bigint and nvarchar(128)):



RECORD_KEY
MODIFIER_LIST_RECORD_KEY
NAME




5992441193994846327
5992426424268357750
CHOOSE ICE CREAM



[ITEM_MODIFIER] table (datatypes bigint, bigint and bigint):



RECORD_KEY
ITEM_RECORD_KEY
MODIFIER_LIST_RECORD_KEY




3189656801236120901
3189656780758021441
5992426424268357750



[MODIFIER] table (datatypes bigint, bigint, nvarchar(128), bigint and nvarchar(64)):



RECORD_KEY
MODIFIER_GROUP_RECORD_KEY
NAME
ITEM_RECORD_KEY
UPCHARGE_EXPRESSION




5992479917748650109
5992441193994846327
NULL
5935753858146389769
$0.00


5992548895904366727
5992441193994846327
NULL
5935753875199381267
$0.00


5992553113958285448
5992441193994846327
NULL
5935753877166837524
$0.00


5992590751191728269
5992441193994846327
NULL
5935753885692612377
$0.00


5992596587928879246
5992441193994846327
NULL
5935753887661641498
$0.00


5992752244786331827
5992441193994846327
NULL
5935753956554460991
$0.00


5992774327866622137
5992441193994846327
NULL
5935753967705804613
$0.00


5992784415143821500
5992441193994846327
NULL
5935753973608501064
$0.00


5993568288307740930
5992441193994846327
CHOOSE LATER
NULL
0.00



I believe I need to add a second select statement for the MODIFIER table to pull the items names using the ITEM_RECORD_KEY and ITEM.NAME, but I am not sure how to do this or if this is even the correct thing to do.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

SSMS is just an IDE (like) application that is used with several products such as (but not limited to) SQL Server, Azure SQL Edge and Azure Synapse. SSMS is likely irrelevant to the question here. What product are you actually using for your data engine? Tagging [[tag:SSMS]] for your data engine is like tagging [[tag:visual-studio]] for your programming language; it doesn't actually really tell us anything.

The query in your image and the one in your question differ; the former has a WHERE. All those RIGHT JOINs "smell" aswell. Also, why use a GROUP BY? You have no aggregation.

Seems that your problem is a mix of incorrect data and incorrect query. I tried to replicate your issue on this sample fiddle, but it's really hard. You obviously have a mistake in the table item_modifier. There, the MODIFIER_LIST_RECORD_KEY should be 5992426424268357750 rather than 5992261445370970226. Furthermore, the GROUP BY clause is incorrect and the reason why you get less rows than intended. I would also use LEFT JOIN, it's much simpler than RIGHT JOIN (see my fiddle).

I fixed the ITEM_MODIFIER table and updated the MODIFIER_LIST_RECORD_KEY.

@JonasMetzler I see that you made progress by removing the group by statement.  It would be ok to have a second column that displays the Item Name of the modifier to the right of the NAME column if that makes it easier rather than trying to combine both the Name and the ITEM_RECORD_KEY column together.

I was able to find the solution for the query with the assistance of my friend Gregg
This is the final query that returns the NON-ITEM and ITEM Modifiers and combines them in a single column using COALENCE.  I thought I needed to join the ITEM_RECORD_KEY from the ITEM_MODIFIER table when I needed to join the ITEM table (Last LEFT JOIN).
SELECT
I.NAME AS 'ITEM NAME'
,ML.NAME AS 'MODIFIER LIST'
,MG.NAME AS 'MODIFIER GROUP'
,COALESCE(M.NAME,IR.name)  AS 'MODIFIER'
,FORMAT(CAST(M.UPCHARGE_EXPRESSION AS numeric), 'c', 'en-us') AS 'UPCHARGE'
FROM ITEM i
LEFT JOIN ITEM_MODIFIER IM ON IM.ITEM_RECORD_KEY = I.RECORD_KEY
LEFT JOIN MODIFIER_LIST ML ON ML.RECORD_KEY = IM.MODIFIER_LIST_RECORD_KEY
LEFT JOIN MODIFIER_GROUP MG ON MG.MODIFIER_LIST_RECORD_KEY = ML.RECORD_KEY
LEFT JOIN MODIFIER M ON M.MODIFIER_GROUP_RECORD_KEY = MG.RECORD_KEY
LEFT JOIN ITEM IR ON IR.RECORD_KEY = M.ITEM_RECORD_KEY
WHERE ML.NAME IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY I.NAME, ML.NAME, MG.NAME, M.NAME, IR.NAME, M.UPCHARGE_EXPRESSION
ORDER BY I.NAME, ML.NAME, MG.NAME, M.NAME

Here you can find the query in action using db<>fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/tU8tHmJC

I cannot really understand your data model.
Why do you have the item to sell "$2 sundae sale" in the same table as the modifiers?
As Jonas Metzler states in his comment, the issue may not only be with your query but also with your data.
If I understand correctly your model correctly:
There are items for sale (the $2 sundae) which the customer can modify.
There are modifiers which are grouped into modifier groups.
Finally based on the choice of modifier there may be an upcharge for the sale item.
If this is correct the following data model makes more sense and would simplify your queries (I use * to denote the PK).
The table with the items for sale ($2 sunday)
SALE_ITEMS
----------
* RECORD_KEY
NAME

The table with all the modifiers (COOKIE DOUGH IC, BLACK RASP IC, etc.)
MODIFIERS
---------
* RECORD_KEY
NAME

The table with the group of modifiers (Ice cream flavour)
MODIFIER_GROUPS 
---------------
* RECORD_KEY
NAME

The table that groups modifiers into groups (both columns form the primary key for the table).
MODIFIER_GROUPING
-----------------
* MODIFIER_GROUP_RECORD_KEY
* MODIFIER_RECORD_KEY

The table that lists which modifier groups can be applied to each sale item.
The CHOOSE_LATER column is a boolean (0,1) to define whether the user can choose the modifier later (whatever later means). This is instead of a separate entry in the table with the upcharges.
ITEM_MODIFIERS
--------------
* SALE_ITEM_RECORD_KEY
* MODIFIER_GROUP_RECORD_KEY
CHOOSE_LATER

Table with the upcharge for sale item based on the modifier. Note that upcharge $0 can be the default, so this table only needs to have entries for modifiers that actually increase the price of the item.
UPCHARGES
---------
* SALE_ITEM_RECORD_KEY
* MODIFIER_GROUP_RECORD_KEY
* MODIFIER_RECORD_KEY


I did not design the database.  The ITEM table holds all Items for sale.  Any item in the ITEM table can be used to modify the base item for sale.  In this example, the "$2 Sundae Sale" Item has a modifier List called "Ice Cream Flavors".  Under "Ice Cream Flavors" there is a Modifier Group Called "Choose Ice Cream".  This holds the list of modifiers.  I have provided a screenshot of my query showing my query does return a result with no errors.  It is just not returning the rows from the Modifier table "ITEM_RECORD_KEY" column.  I believe I need to add a separate select query to return these

The reason that items from the ITEM table can be used as modifiers is for inventory purposes.  For example, needing to track inventory on the different flavors of ice cream being sold.  There is no need to track "Choose Later" so this is a NON-ITEM added to the NAME column.  All inventory modifiers are entered in the ITEM_RECORD_KEY COLUMN.  In my report query I need to display the modifier name from the NAME column and the Item Name from the ITEM Table referenced in the ITEM_RECORD_KEY column.

It is too bad that the schema does match the object domain, but that unfortunately is often the case. You do understand that the "$2 sundae sale" and the flavours are inherently different. Ice cream flavours have physical inventory, but the sundae itself does not (as it is made of ice cream flavours).
Are all the items in the table offered for sale, i.e. will I see "COOKIE DOUGH IC" in the same interface as "$2 sundae sale"? That sounds like a nightmare.  If there is a table that specifies which items are for sale and which are just there for inventory it could be used to simplify your query.

Your question here has no benefit in solving my question.  However, I will provide an explanation.  "$2 sundae sale" is a valid item to track   There could be unlimited items like this That I want to track.  For example, $3..., $4,....Happy meal.., extra.  Not only can I see how many of these I have sold (what promotion or package sold the most or did not perform, each of these have items attached that need to be tracked.  What flavors, how many scoops that can be directly tied to how much in OZ/LBs or how many burger patties, was sold.  This then can be checked against inventory purchased.

To add a bit more clarity to my exclamation above.

A roast beef sandwich lunch special could include a cup of soup or side salad.  Both the  cup of soup and side salad would be a modifier to the roast beef sandwich and all 3 would be added to the item table.  All three of these could be sold separately.  The roast beef sandwich special can be tracked to determine if more cups of soup or side salads were selected.  There are many benefits of using items as modifiers.

I understand and apologize I cannot help with your question. This is more a comment than an answer but cannot fit as a comment. The problem is that your domain does not neatly map into a relational structure. You still have several different classes of items:
Items for sale and items that are just ingredients of the for sale items and not directly offered for sale.
Then the sale items themselves may be composed into packages with other sale items.

You are basically mapping hierarchies inside a table.  This is known to be difficult which is why many DBs offer specialized query constructs to tackle them (search for hierarchical queries in ).
